# Microsoft Excel, copying Format of a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

Like copy and pasting cell content with format to another cell or multiple cells, **is there a way to copy a particular cell's FORMAT alone and paste using Ctrl+V to another/multiple cells?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no special copy format only command, but there is `Paste Special` for which one of the options is `format`.

Comment: @Tyson Actually, there is. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Format Painter to quickly copy formatting from one thing in a document to another. Select the thing you like the look of, click Format Painter, and then click the thing you want to change to look the same. If you want to copy the formatting to more than one thing, double-click instead of single-clicking Format Painter. To exit the Format Painter, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Format Painter picks up all the formatting from your first thing, whether it’s a shape, cell, picture border, or piece of text, and applies it to the second. This way, you can spend your time getting the first thing right, and apply the same formatting wherever you want in your document with a couple of clicks.

**Excel**

1. Select the shape, text, picture, or worksheet cell with the
   formatting you want to copy.
2. Click `Home`, and in the `Clipboard` group, click `Format Painter`.

   [image: Format Painter on the Home tab in Excel]
3. After the pointer changes to a paintbrush, select the shape, text,
   or worksheet cell that you want to format.

   To copy the formatting to a single cell, several cells, or a range or ranges of cells, drag the mouse pointer across the cells or ranges of cells that you want to format.

`TIP` To quickly copy the width of one column to a second column, select the heading of the first column, click Format Painter, and then click the heading of the second column. You can’t copy the column width if the column contains a merged cell.

[ [Source](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Copy-formatting-using-the-Format-Painter-b9fe82ea-c0a0-41de-837b-d2f15dd41ea9) ]

Comment: You can also copy the formatting to several cells by double-clicking "Format Painter".